# block 202612 , how been findet this value?

Tags: blockchain, development, altcoin

how been findet this value

```
 bool get_block_longhash(const block& b, crypto::hash& res, uint64_t height)
  {
    // block 202612 bug workaround
    const std::string longhash_202612 = "84f64766475d51837ac9efbef1926486e58563c95a19fef4aec3254f03000000";
    if (height == 202612)
    {
      string_tools::hex_to_pod(longhash_202612, res);
      return true;
    }
    blobdata bd = get_block_hashing_blob(b);
    crypto::cn_slow_hash(bd.data(), bd.size(), res);
    return true;
  }
```

i try to figurate what write to console or how it calculate for see it. And where to see it.

Comment: It's pow , i find answer

Answer (score 1):

It's pow value , can be find at set_log 2